# How to create a crack in the ground that develops over time

Tags: geometry-nodes, procedural, simulation-nodes

I'm relatively new to blender and I'm trying to create an effect where I have a ground plane and a crack should develop from the left to the right of the plane over time. I have no idea where to start, I was thinking using geometry nodes or procedural texture but I'm not sure. If anyone has done something like this before or has any ideas that would be very helpful. Here is a reference video of what I'm trying to do: https://www.youtube.com/shorts/rR24QERKtFo

Comment: That particular reference looks to me as if the entire crack has been constructed,  and its growth laid in with a simple wipe, maybe shaped,  in 2D post: (compositing). It's blurry at the tip.

Answer (score 3):

**Line of Empties**

We create an **empty** to control the damage.  The closer it gets to the surface, the smaller the pieces of asphalt get, and the more they are pushed downward.

We create a slab of concrete, (add your favorite material to a flat rectangular cube). Use the **cell fracture add-on** to break into pieces, probably 200 or more small pieces, creating a collection.

[image]

We create another object, a plane to hold this geometry node tree:

[image]

After completing the node tree we have something like this. (Hide the cell fracture collection, otherwise no effect.)

[image]

It isn't making the shape we want, but basically from here, we are just repeating what we have already built. **We make a group** (ctrl+g) selecting our existing nodes.  The selected group will look like this:

[image]

We can then repeat what we have done with more empties.  In order to this we create a line of empties that will cross the entire length of our concrete slab.   We can reuse the group several times.

[image]
[image]

End result, when we drop the line of empties on the surface it creates the fracture, and we can adjust the animation to get the exact effect we want.

[image]

Next step, shot matching, and compositing!